# Python Multiprocessing module unexpected outputs. What can be the cause of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

I am learning the multiprocessing module of Python. I am on Python 3.8. This is my sample code:

```
# import stuff

def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f'{x + y} \n')


def main():

    start = time.perf_counter()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p1 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(100, 200))
        p2 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(200, 300))
        p1.start(); p2.start()
        p1.join(); p2.join()

    end = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'{end - start} seconds \n')


main()
```

I am expecting outputs such as:

```
300

500

10.something seconds
```

But when I run it I am getting:

```
5.999999999062311e-07 seconds 
5.00000000069889e-07 seconds 


500 

300 

10.704853300000002 seconds
```

For some reason the `end = time.perf_counter(); print(f'{end - start} seconds \n')` part is getting executed once after each process is started and one more time after they both end. But here I am specifically writing `p1.join(); p2.join()` to tell the computer to wait until these processes are finished and then move on to the following line of code.

Why is it behaving like this? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @dano, I am on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are running on Windows, which does not support `fork`. On Linux, I see the output you expect. Because Windows can't fork, it has to re-import your entire module in each child process in order to run your worker function. Because you're not protecting the code that calculates/prints the runtime in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, they are executed in both of your worker processes when they are launched, in addition to running in your main process once the workers finish. Move them (and any other code you only want to run in the parent process) into the guard to get the output you want:

```py
# import stuff

def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f'{x + y} \n')


def main():
    p1 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(100, 200))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=add, args=(200, 300))
    p1.start(); p2.start()
    p1.join(); p2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There is a small mistake. It should be `'__main__'` instead of `'__main__"`